# Arabic words coloring not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor, contenteditable, arabic, styling

Arabic words coloring not working in Chrome and 
its perfectly working in Firefox.

Below is my sentence in arabic

بِسْمِ ٱللهِ ٱلرَّحْمٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ

And I am storing that sentence in database

MySql - MyISAM - utf8_unicode_ci

with CkEditor 4

Now, When i want to color that sentence in chrome, the word letters are broken up.
Where as in firefox, its working good.

[image: Firefoxe screenshot]

[image: Chrome screenshot]

### Updated with html code in Ckeditor

In Chrome,

```
<p><span style="font-size:48px"><span style="color:#FFF0F5"><span style="background-color:#008000">بِسْمِ ٱللهِ</span></span><span style="color:#008000"><span style="background-color:#FFF0F5"> ٱ</span></span><span style="color:#FF8C00"><span style="background-color:#FFF0F5">ل</span></span><span style="color:#FF0000"><span style="background-color:#FFF0F5">رَّ</span></span><span style="color:#008000"><span style="background-color:#FFF0F5">حْ</span></span><span style="color:#0000FF"><span style="background-color:#FFF0F5">مٰنِ</span></span><span style="color:#008000"><span style="background-color:#FFF0F5"> ٱلرَّحِيمِ</span></span></span></p>
```

In Firefox,

```
<p><span style="font-size:48px"><span style="color:rgb(255, 240, 245)"><span style="background-color:rgb(0, 128, 0)">بِسْمِ ٱللهِ</span></span><span style="color:rgb(0, 128, 0)"><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 240, 245)"> ٱ</span></span><span style="color:rgb(255, 140, 0)"><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 240, 245)">ل</span></span><span style="color:#FF0000"><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 240, 245)">رَّ</span></span><span style="color:rgb(0, 128, 0)"><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 240, 245)">حْ</span></span><span style="color:rgb(0, 0, 255)"><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 240, 245)">مٰنِ</span></span><span style="color:rgb(0, 128, 0)"><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 240, 245)"> ٱلرَّحِيمِ</span></span></span></p>
```

Comment: It looks like rendering bug in the web browser, a problem with [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) rather than CKEditor. Please include HTML of your contents from the screenshot in your question.

Comment: @oleq I dont think so, contenditable is far away from CKEditor. and I have updated the question with html source code from editor.